# chrome notification não aparece

Tags: javascript-eventos, push-notification

Boa noite, estou executando um código para apresentar uma notificação:

```
if(Notification.permission === 'granted' && !this._active) {
    let n = new Notification(this._activeContact.name,{
       icon : this._activeContact.photo,
       body : data.content
    });
```

Mas nenhuma notificação está aparecendo!
O que pode estar acontecendo?

A permissão já está positiva

*****editado****

o código q pede a permissão é esse: 
alias, não está funcionando no edge...

```
checkNotifications(){
    // debugger
    if (typeof Notification === 'function'){
        if (Notification.permission !== 'granted'){
            this.el.alertNotificationPermission.show()
        } else {
            this.el.alertNotificationPermission.hide()
        }

        this.el.alertNotificationPermission.on('click', e=> {
            Notification.requestPermission(permission => {
                if (permission === 'granted') {
                    this.el.alertNotificationPermission.hide()
                    console.info('notificações permitidas!')
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou fazer a chamada dele usando `requestPermission`?

```
Notification.requestPermission()
```

Comment: sim lucas, eu tenho um método que está fazendo isso... vou editar a pergunta pra mostrar!!